# Inbound policy in Azure VM is not working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have created a VM in Azure. Also I have created a Point to Site VPN . It works fine when I have created the inbound policy as Source= any , destination=any, Service =RDP , Action =Allow. 
But the real scenario in my case is that , I need to create inbound policy in such a way that, i can do the rdp to the azure vm  only from address pool which I have created for Virtual network gateway.

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you want to block all the traffic from the internet except your P2S ?

Comment: I want to do the rdp . Actually now I am not able to do rdp when I connect via azure P2S vpn connection .  No, I don't  want to block all traffic from the internet.

Comment: can you ping your azure internal IP address from you P2S client?

Comment: I was able to ping . I have followed the document  and it was working.  [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site)  .  But since i need extra security for my VM I need to add an inbound policy so that I can do the rdp only the address pool which i have created for virtual network gateway .

Comment: can you use VM's internal IP address to RDP?

Comment: only set NSG to Source= any , destination=any, Service =RDP , Action =Allow, you will able to RDP vm via p2s VPN?

Comment: No , I use only public ip address for RDP . But I was able to ping to internal ip too , but not able to ping the public ip.                                      Actually I tried to edit that default inbound security rule so that I can only do RDP from the  Network Security Gateway Address pool. But it doesn't worked at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139821/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-botguide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you connect P2S VPN, we should use internal IP address to RDP VM.

Update:

we can use NSG inbound security rule **advanced** to set it.
[image]